# Numba cuda is compiling but not working, without throwing exceptions

Tags: exception, cuda, jit, numba

I am trying to write a simple function to test why numba.cuda isn't working. The function should set a variable to a fixed value. When I call the function, it seems to compile, but nothing happens. I added, that it should raise an exception, just to see, that it gets called, but again nothing happens. I don't get any kind of exception to give me a hint, why it is not working.

Function:

```
from numba import cuda


@cuda.jit     # also tried it with brackets: @cuda.jit()
def cuda_func(out):
    out = 1
    raise NameError('MyException')
```

I call the funtction like this:

```
>>> import Cuda_Class
>>> a = 0
>>> Cuda_Class.cuda_func[1, 1](a)
>>> a
0
```

`numba.cuda.is_available` returns True.

I am working inside a miniconda environment and had some trouble with installing cuda. I accidentally installed multiple versions, so I had to purge everything, and installed cuda 10.2 in my base environment. In the conda environment I installed the cudatoolkit (10.2.89).

I set `CUDA_HOME` to `/usr/local/cuda-10.2`. So `nvcc --version` gives me the right version. So the compiler is accessible.

`NUMBA_CUDA_DRIVER` should lead to `cudalib.so`, which I had trouble finding. I did not manually install the nvidia driver, it was installed in combination with cuda. I found cudalib.so under `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs/libcuda.so`. There was no other file named libcuda.so, only `libcuda.so.7`. However, even before I set NUMBA_CUDA_DRIVER and it was empty, the behavior was exactly the same. No reaction, no exceptions. It looks as if the function would be called correctly, but nothing happens.

The only idea I have left is, that maybe it is a problem, that libcuda.so is in a "stubs" folder?

Comment: If you wrote that code without the exception (which are not supported in CUDA kernels) in plain Python, would you expect the value of a to change after calling the function? Integers are immutable.

Comment: It says [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html) that numba supports the raise function in CUDA python. Therefore, I assuemd it also supports the raising of an exception. 
Yes I did expect that. I cannot return a value in the kernel function. I just changed it to be a numpy array and altered the first value. Now it actually changed. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that raising an exception within a cuda compiled function (with some sort of conditional guard of course) is not an explicitly bad thing. I have found it helpful for when I set the environment variable `NUMBA_ENABLE_CUDASIM=1` then set various exception conditions and assert statements in my device functions to catch logic errors and unexpected behavior. Normally `assert` and `exceptions` are not compiled, but using that environment variable toggles the cuda simulator and allows for more pythonic debugging; however, note that the simulator really, really, slows things down.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment solved my problem:

1. I tried to change the value of an immutable Integer.
2. Although `raise` is supported by numba.cuda, apparently exceptions are not supported.

Neither of those mistakes lead to an error message.

Changing "out" to an array and manipulating the first value works.